# How sum Twig Template

Tags: foreach, attributes, sum, twig

i have code 
        {% for defect in data %}

```
            <td>{{ defect.name }}</td>
             {% for times in time %}
             <td>{{ attribute(defect, times) }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          <tr>
              <td>Total</td>
               {% for times in time %}
               <td>in here</td>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
```

i want to sum  {{ attribute(defect, times) }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have too many `{% endfor %}` tags.

But what you can do is something like this:

```
{% set total = 0 %}
...
   {% for times in time %}
   {% set total = total + attribute(defect, times) %}
...

<td>Total equals: {{ total }}</td>
```

Essentially creating a variable called `total` and then in your loop add the attribute value. Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Hi there Fahmi. Did my answer solve the problem? If so can you click the checkmark next to my answer? That marks it as the correct answer and so if people search for this, they can find a correct answer. Thanks!